# Code review needed for my Prime factorization code

Tags: python, primes

Below is the code for knowing all the prime factors of a number. I think there must be some better way of doing the same thing. Also, please tell me if there are some flaws in my code.

```
def factorize(num):
    res2 = "%s: "%num
    res = []
    while num != 1:
        for each in range(2, num + 1):
            quo, rem = divmod(num, each)
            if not rem:
                res.append(each)
                break
        num = quo
    pfs = set(res)
    for each in pfs:
        power = res.count(each)
        if power == 1:
            res2 += str(each) + " "
        else:
            res2 += str(each) + '^' + str(power) + " "
    return res2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def factorize(num):
    res2 = "%s: "%num
```

You'd be much better off to put the string stuff in a seperate function. Just have this function return the list of factors, i.e. `res` and have a second function take `res` as a parameter and return the string. That'd make your logic simpler for each function.

```
    res = []
```

Don't needlessly abbreviate. It doesn't save you any serious amount of typing time and makes it harder to follow your code.

```
    while num != 1:
        for each in range(2, num + 1):
```

To be faster here, you'll want recompute the prime factors of the numbers. You can use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Just keep track of the prime factors found, and you'll just be able to look them up.

```
            quo, rem = divmod(num, each)
            if not rem:
                res.append(each)
                break
        num = quo
```

Your function dies here if you pass it a zero.

```
    pfs = set(res)
```

Rather than a set, use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), it'll let you get the counts at the same time rather then recounting res.

```
    for each in pfs:
        power = res.count(each)
        if power == 1:
            res2 += str(each) + " "
        else:
            res2 += str(each) + '^' + str(power) + " "
```

String addition is inefficient. I'd suggest using `"{}^{}".format(each, power)`. Also, store each piece in a list and then use `" ".join` to make them into a big string at the end.

```
    return res2
```